# System.IO.FileSystemWatcher fired only one time

Tags: powershell, file-watcher

Requirement is as follows

- Thru FTP client, user will upload file on FTP server
- Once file is copied, we need to process it and call batch file
- Once done, will wait for another file

Below script is running fine for one file, but for next file, no action event is not fired.

```
### SET FOLDER TO WATCH + FILES TO WATCH + SUBFOLDERS YES/NO
$watcher = New-Object System.IO.FileSystemWatcher
$watcher.Path = "C:\folder\xmls"
$watcher.Filter = "*.*"
$watcher.IncludeSubdirectories = $true
$watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = $true

### DEFINE ACTIONS AFTER A EVENT IS DETECTED
$action = {
    $path = $Event.SourceEventArgs.FullPath

    ### Sleep for 30 seconds
    Start-Sleep -s 30

    $changeType = $Event.SourceEventArgs.ChangeType
    $date = Get-Date
    $logFile = "C:\folder\Log_" +  $date.ToString("yyyyMMdd") + ".txt"
    $logline = "$(Get-Date), $changeType, $path"
    Add-Content -Path $logFile -Value $logline

    $logline = "$(Get-Date), MLCP process started"
    Add-Content -Path $logFile -Value $logline

    Start-Process -FilePath 'C:\folder\import.bat' -ArgumentList @('"' + $path + '"') -Wait

    $logline = "$(Get-Date), MLCP process completed"
    Add-Content -Path $logFile -Value $logline

    $destinationPath = "C:\folder\ProcessedXmls"
    ###Copy file to processed folder
    Move-Item -Path $path -Destination $destinationPath -Force

    $logline = "$(Get-Date), File moved to processed folder"
    Add-Content -Path $logFile -Value $logline

    $logline = "$(Get-Date), Call Upload script"
    Add-Content -Path $logFile -Value $logline

    $scriptToRun = "C:\folder\UploadStatustoBlob.ps1"

    &$scriptToRun

    Log($logFile, "Upload script completed from function")

    $logline = "$(Get-Date), Upload script completed"
    Add-Content -Path $logFile -Value $logline
}

### DECIDE WHICH EVENTS SHOULD BE WATCHED + SET CHECK FREQUENCY
$created = Register-ObjectEvent $watcher Created -Action $action

while ($true) {sleep 1}
```

If I again restart PowerShell desktop app, it is working for 1st file.

I then need to add this to Windows Task Scheduler for continuous running.

I am not sure what I am missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Going back to something more minimal, this works without the While.

```
$Source = 'E:\Temp\folder\xmls'
$Filter = '*.*'
$destination = 'E:\Temp\Folder\ProcessedXmls'

$Watcher = New-Object IO.FileSystemWatcher $Source, $filter -Property @{
    IncludeSubdirectories = $true
    NotifyFilter = [IO.NotifyFilters]'FileName, LastWrite'
}

$onCreated = Register-ObjectEvent $Watcher Created -SourceIdentifier FileCreated -Action {
    Start-Sleep -Seconds 3
    $Path = $Event.SourceEventArgs.FullPath
    Move-Item $Path -Destination $destination -verbose
}


# Results    

VERBOSE: Performing the operation "Move File" on target "Item: E:\Temp\folder\xmls\New Text Document.txt Destination: E:\Temp\Folder\ProcessedXmls\New Text Document.txt".
VERBOSE: Performing the operation "Move File" on target "Item: E:\Temp\folder\xmls\New Text Document - Copy.txt Destination: E:\Temp\Folder\ProcessedXmls\New TextDocument - Copy.txt".
VERBOSE: Performing the operation "Move File" on target "Item: E:\Temp\folder\xmls\New Bitmap Image.bmp Destination: E:\Temp\Folder\ProcessedXmls\New Bitmap Image.bmp".
```

As does adding the bare minimum I could validate on my end.

```
$Source = 'E:\Temp\folder\xmls'
$Filter = '*.*'
$destination = 'E:\Temp\Folder\ProcessedXmls'

$Watcher = New-Object IO.FileSystemWatcher $Source, $filter -Property @{
 IncludeSubdirectories = $true
 NotifyFilter = [IO.NotifyFilters]'FileName, LastWrite'
}

$onCreated = Register-ObjectEvent $Watcher Created -SourceIdentifier FileCreated -Action {
    Start-Sleep -Seconds 3
    $Path = $Event.SourceEventArgs.FullPath

    $date = Get-Date
    $logFile = "E:\Temp\folder\Log_" +  $date.ToString("yyyyMMdd") + ".txt"
    $logline = "$(Get-Date), $changeType, $path"
    Add-Content -Path $logFile -Value $logline

    Move-Item $Path -Destination $destination -verbose

    $logline = "$(Get-Date), File moved to processed folder"
    Add-Content -Path $logFile -Value $logline
}

# Log file content --- Log_20190419.txt

04/19/2019 00:40:12, , E:\Temp\folder\xmls\New Text Document.txt
04/19/2019 00:40:12, File moved to processed folder
04/19/2019 00:40:28, , E:\Temp\folder\xmls\New Text Document - Copy.txt
04/19/2019 00:40:28, File moved to processed folder
04/19/2019 00:40:46, , E:\Temp\folder\xmls\New Bitmap Image.bmp
04/19/2019 00:40:46, File moved to processed folder
```

Also, the sleep is not really needed. Moves are immediate of course if you don't set that.

Comment: Thanks postanote for your reply.
If i do not keep while then script will end running, so then how it will execute for next file. If i keep this running in task scheduler, so as soon as 1st execute finished, how to make sure it keep running

Comment: No worries --- What you are seeing are actual run results. Nope, no need for the while, as show in my post the actual results of live runs, that will continue to run until you close the PowerShell session or remove the event.

Comment: Thanks postanote for your reply, same will run in task scheduler also?

Comment: Hello postanote, i executed it in powershell console, still it was not picking up the next file, i have copied the script you mentioned above, but not sure what is missing here?

Comment: Remember I could only test with part of your use case. If I left the lines that are specific to your environment in, then it would only run once. Using my post back exactly as is, should work, as is, that is exactly what I tested, but I did that test in the ISE not the console. However, I just ran both of my segments in the consolehost, and they both work as shown. Do you have another machine to test on?

Comment: Hello Postanote, it worked, i discovered that, as it is kind of async process, if error comes in between, it does not throw any exception but it stop running, i then added few more log entry and found the code where exception occurs and now its working, Thanks for your help

Comment: No worries, and glad to hear it got you going.

Comment: @ManishJoisar hi, currently facing the same issue, would you mind detailing what your specific problem was (the one that appeared when added some log lines) ? I'm at a loss, really : script works perfectly on 1 PC (never misses a creation or deletion), works once and then fails on another PC... I really don't get it, but it think this thread can help  me.